# Help installing on Surface Pro 2

Tags: system-installation, surface-tablet

I'm having trouble installing elementary OS onto my Surface Pro 2. elementary OS works fine when in live mode - except that Wi-Fi doesn't work (driver issue, I guess?).

When I try a proper install, the resolution is much too low and most of the dialog is clipped off. Nevertheless, I have managed to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>arrow-key</kbd> my way through to the install step. But at some point it crashes with some error related to `grub`.

I'd really like to get elementary OS working on this machine. What can I try? And how can I gather better diagnostics to help get to the bottom of the problem?

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of tinkering I managed to get Elementary installed.This [very helpful guide](https://github.com/skylerseverns/elementary-os-freya-uefi/blob/master/installing-elementary-os-freya.md) walked me through installing Freya on a UEFI based system using the rEFInd boot manager instead of GRUB2.

The DPI wasn't right after install, even though the resolution was set to 1920x1080. Running this command (mentioned in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2d8qwm/freya_scaling_problem/)) fixed the problem:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1`

Although now the DPI is a bit too high and it is difficult to make out writing. I'll investigate this further. But at least it is installed and running!