# How to add a package to the live CD (iso)?

Tags: system-installation, package-management, iso

I'm having trouble installing on my Surface Pro (see [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/help-installing-on-surface-pro-2)) and I suspect that it is related to this recent [bug fix](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/congrego-freya/revision/122) on LaunchPad. The Surface is a UEFI based system, which might explain why GRUB fails to install.

How can I add the `grub-efi-amd64` and `grub-efi-amd64-signed` packages to an ISO to test out this theory? I have tried checking out the branch with Bazaar and building it with `sudo ./congrego.sh` but this fails with this error:

`E: Cannot install into target '/media/elliot/d2/elementary/freya/tmp/amd64/chroot' mounted with noexec or nodev`

Comment: I found a tutorial by Ubuntu Community itself. I do not know if it'll work for elementary or not. You better read it, try if it seems promising. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization     It IS lengthy

Comment: Thanks for the info @Adityaultra. I've managed to get Elementary installed now using an alternative method (see [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/help-installing-on-surface-pro-2)).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of EFI/UEFI issues have been fixed in Elementary os 0.3.2, If you was not using this new update try it.

You shoudn't need to add anything to your iso. Is your linux installed without grub or not installed at all becose of grub ? Can you boot with super grub2 disk installed on a usb? if yes use boot repair from line usb or learn about rescatux witch is a distro able to install and fix grub.

I have performed with sucess an UEFI install or elementary OS, and an other one on external hard drive where grub failed to install but I can boot from super grub2 disk